# MVC3: Custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am implementing a `Custom Authorize Attribute` in `MVC3`. I am storing page level permissions in the database, and would like to pass my authorize attribute a Page ID. Something of the sort:

```
[CustomAuthorize(PageID = 1)]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

How do I implement the `Authorize Attribute`, as the `AuthorizeCore` only takes one argument in the override?

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would define a class-level variable to hold the PageID, and your attribute's constructor would take that as an argument. Or to use it like you have in your example, you would create a public property called PageID.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public int PageID{get; set;}

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
         //use PageID to do checks here.
    }
}
```

Then within your `AuthorizeCore`, you would use that property/field value to do your checks.

Answer (score 0):

(Custom User Type ) Just some tweaking

Test Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace Authorise.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /Default1/
        [CustomAuthorize(UserType = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }

    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string UserType { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (UserType == "Admin")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<h2>Test</h2>
```

Account Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Authorise.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Account Logon View

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "LogOn";
}
```

### LogOn